# Unhealthy Worker role is not restarting and waiting for the status

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles

I have a worker-role, 4 instances, with external TCP/IP endpoint. After several days running without problems, instances began to die, one after one.

In 24 hours all of them were in status: 
"Waiting for the status (Role has reported itself as unhealthy.)".

All of them were sending "Working" verbose to log (from Run method), but not accepting any incoming connections. How this could happen ? Unhandled exception from some thread ?

Why all of them were not restarted even after several hours and all of them were just "waiting for the status" ?

Answer (score 0):

If they're endlessly repeating the startup-shutdown-restart cycle, then one possibility is that you have a startup task that works the first time it's run but fails on subsequent runs (ie, it is not idempotent).

Otherwise, it could be that something in your startup process is causing a problem, but it's hard to say without more information. Try to RDP into the machines and look at the Windows Event Logs, and anything else you can think of, for clues.

You might also try Reimaging one or two instances and see if that fixes the problem. That would at least tell you if the problem is in the base code, or if the VM got into some unrecoverable state.

Comment: They were not repeating startup-shutdown-restart at all. For several hours just in state: _"Waiting for the status (Role has reported itself as unhealthy.)"_. After manual restart they are working normally.